# How to modify fragment of base jinja2 when extends?

Tags: python, jinja2

I have next two jinja2 files:

**base.jinja2:**

```
{% block blk1 %}
key1:
  val1:
    val11: {{ my_value }}
  val2: {{ my_value }}
{% endblock blk1 -%}
```

**extends.jinja2:**

```
{% extends 'base.jinja2' %}
```

I have next python file to use above jinji2 file:

**test.py:**

```
import jinja2
template_loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(["."])
env = jinja2.Environment(loader=template_loader)
TEMPLATE_FILE = "extends.jinja2"
template = env.get_template(TEMPLATE_FILE)
ctx = {"my_value": 10}
output = template.render(ctx)
print(output)
```

**The execution output:**

```
# python3 test.py

key1:
  val1:
    val11: 10
  val2: 10
```

**My problem:**

I wish the execution above could be next which add a `val12`:

```
key1:
  val1:
    val11: 10
    val12: 10
  val2: 10
```

**YES**, I could change `base.jinja2` to next:

```
{% block blk1 %}
key1:
  val1:
    val11: {{ my_value }}
    val12: {{ my_value }}
  val2: {{ my_value }}
{% endblock blk1 -%}
```

**BUT**, the problem is: `base.jinja2` & `test.py` comes from an opensource project which I can't change them, what I can change is `extends.jinja2`.

If possible I could just modify `extends.jinja2` to meet my requirement? Something like next:

```
{% extends 'base.jinja2' %}
{% block blk1 %}
# some solution extends the thing from blk1 of base.jinja2
key1:
  val1:
    val12: {{ my_value }}
{% endblock blk1 -%}
```

Above certainly not work, could we do something alike above?

**UPDATE:**

Currently I can just use `super()` as next:

```
{% extends 'base.jinja2' %}
{% block blk1 %}
{{ super() }}
    val12: {{ my_value }}
{% endblock blk1 -%}
```

But this only output:

```
# python3 test.py

key1:
  val1:
    val11: 10
  val2: 10

    val12: 10
```

I still can't put `val12` under `val11`, if any other way to meet my requirement?

Comment: Is it an option to fork the open source base, and customise to your requirements?

Comment: @S3DEV We are active depends on the new features of that big project, this will make us encountered merge effort everytime they upgrade. In fact, currently I do just as you suggested, but I want to find a better way. Meanwhile, our upstream for `base.jinaj2` did not get response from that project.

Comment: So, I wonder if I miss some jinja2 embed feature, which could directly merge the dict for me?